# ¿Como generar un numero random de una longitud específica en java?

Tags: java

Hola he estado investigando sobre números aleatorios, necesito crear un numero random de 5 cifras, es decir que cada vez que genere ese numero sea aleatorio, positivo y de 5 cifras.
Lo he resuelto utilizando la clase Random de esta manera:

```
while(true){
        Random r=new Random();
        int num=r.nextInt();
        int cantidad=(int)Math.abs(Math.log10(num)+1);


        if(cantidad<5) num=r.nextInt();
        else if(cantidad>5) num=r.nextInt();
        else{

            System.out.println(num);
            System.out.println(cantidad);
            {break;}    
        }
    }
```

Quiero saber si es la manera más eficáz o si existe otra forma de hacerlo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos, puedes usar el método estático `Math.random()` que devuelve un número `double` de [0, 1).

> **Math.random()**
>   Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Si los números de 5 cifras van de 10000 a 99999, puedes generar un número aleatorio con `Math.random()` y escalarlo.

```
double fiveDigits = 10000 + Math.random() * 90000;
```

En caso que `Math.random()` devuelva el mínimo, `0`, el resultado será `10000 + 0 * 90000`, que es `10000`.
En caso que `Math.random()` devuelva el máximo, `1` (exclusivo), el resultado será `10000 + 1 * 90000`, que es `100000`, pero como el `1` no es `1`, sinó que `0.9999...`, el resultado es realmente `10000 + 0.999... * 90000`, que es `10000 + 89999.9999...`, o sea `99999.999...`.

Una vez hagamos el *casting* de `double` a `int`, tendremos un número [10000, 99999].

```
public int getFiveDigitsNumber() {
    double fiveDigits = 10000 + Math.random() * 90000;
    return (int) fiveDigits;
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta no solo me has aclarado mi pregunta si no me ha quedado mas claro como utilizar el Math.random()!! Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada. Un placer.

Comment: @Gomesld No olvides de aceptar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Random puede obtener un parametro, en este caso un entero, cuando pones ese parametro random siempre te va a dar en este caso un numero entero comprendido entre `0` (inclusivo) y `n` (exclusivo).

Asi que puedes traducirlo a esto:

```
Random r = new Random();
int cantidad = r.nextInt(90000) + 10000;
```

Eso te daría un numero comprendido entre el `10.000` y el `100.000` incluyendo al `10.000` pero **sin incluir** al `100.000` es decir, hasta `99.999`.

Nótese que se pone `90000` puesto que `90000` tiene 5 dígitos quedando el rango de `0` a `89.999`, ahora para asegurar de que el numero resultado siempre sea de `5` dígitos debemos sumar siempre un numero de 5 digitos, en este caso el primer numero minimo de 5 digitos es el `10.000` por esta razón siempre sumamos `10.000`, completando entonces un numero comprendido entre `10.000` (inclusivo) y `100.000` (exclusivo).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me has aclarado mi duda utilizando la clase Random!!